# Unload child AppDomain that contains POS hardware causing CannotUnloadAppDomainException

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I am using .net 4.0, with POS.net 1.12 and I create a hardware class in a new child AppDomain so that any unhandled exceptions do not kill my parent AppDomain.

I can create the child AppDomain and make calls to it no problem. However, if I try to unload the AppDomain I get the exception "CannotUnloadAppDomainException".

I have googled the issue and the exception normally occurs when threads cannot be killed. I do not actually create any new threads in the child class.

I managed to pinpoint the piece of code that causes this error. If I create the POS hardware class and it only creates POS objects then it works fine. If, however, I call method "Open()" on any piece of hardware, then this exception occurs when unloading. Now before I attempt the unload, I close down all hardware and I have made sure the clean up code gets hit, so I am unsure what the issue is.

Here is the code to create and unload the AppDomain:

```
AppDomain hardwareDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Hardware domain");

IHardwareManager hardwareManager =
        (IHardwareManager)hardwareDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(OposHardwareManager).Assembly.Location,
                                                                     typeof(OposHardwareManager).FullName);

hardwareManager.StartupHardware();

hardwareManager.CloseDownHardware();
hardwareManager = null;

// **** causes exception
AppDomain.Unload(hardwareDomain);
```

And here is the hardware class:

```
public class OposHardwareManager : MarshalByRefObject, IHardwareManager
{
    private PosExplorer _posExplorer;
    private PosPrinter _printer;

    public void StartupHardware()
    {
        // create the hardware explorer
        this._posExplorer = new PosExplorer();

        // create and enable the printer
        DeviceInfo printerInfo = this._posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
        PosDevice printerDevice = this._posExplorer.CreateInstance(printerInfo);
        this._printer = (PosPrinter)printerDevice;

        // ***** this line here, if run, causes the exception on unload 
        this._printer.Open();
        this._printer.Claim(2000);
        this._printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
    }

    public void CloseDownHardware()
    {
        this._printer.Release();
        this._printer.Close();

        this._printer = null;
        this._posExplorer = null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing a type in your creating domain (like you do with `typeof(OposHardwareManager)`), the assembly will be loaded in that domain too. When that happens, iow types crossing the domain boundary 'upwards', the created domain cannot be unloaded.

I suggest you do not reference the assembly containing `OposHardwareManager` and simply create it with the full qualified name instead. This may involve some refactoring.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and the same issue arises. I did not think this would fix the problem, as my original code would unload the AppDomain with that assembly no problem, as long as I did not call ".Open()"

Comment: @eyeballpaul: Look at the the debug output window while debugging. It will show you if the assembly is crossing into the creating domain.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by this

Comment: @eyeballpaul: When an assembly is loaded, it will show in the debug window and in which app domain it is loaded. It will load once per app domain, and in your case, I suspect, it is loaded in both app domains, which prevents the unloading.

Comment: It is showing up once in that view. Although for some reason it has the name beside it of "ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe" which would be the parent domain name.

Comment: p.s. I am running it after it has been refactored out, so that the main application has no reference at all to the "OposHardwareManager"

Comment: @eyeballpaul: I think you are on the right path. :) Check that `hardwareManager` is indeed a proxy after creating it. (use `RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy()`).

Comment: Yeah, it is defo a proxy. However, I have come across a bigger issue while trying to solve this. The main reason I was creating a new child AppDomain was so that any unhandled exceptions did not bring down the parent AppDomain. But I have read that the only way to do this is with 2 processes! Now I just need to figure out how to do what I have above with a child process in the main app instead!

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception is your friend here ;p

Comment: BTW doing remoting over app domains or 2 processes are basically the same ;p It is just a little different to setup (but only a few lines of code depending on your transport). Everything else pretty much works the same.

Comment: Here is very simple client/server setup over IPC. https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/blob/master/IronScheme/IronScheme.Remoting.Client/Client.cs https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/blob/master/IronScheme/IronScheme.Remoting.Server/Server.cs The interesting bits are at the top, the rest just implementation details for my own use case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look./ However, the "AppDomain.UnhandledException" would surely only catch any managed exceptions? And not unmanaged exceptions? i.e. third party drivers for hardware.

Comment: @eyeballpaul: .NET should wrap that in some form of catchable exception.

Comment: The issue I have had in the past indicate that it doesn't for all scenarios. I have had unmanaged code crash out the full process. And no amount of catching exceptions, and dealing with unhandled exceptions worked. Hence why I am trying to find the best way to isolate it, and hence why I am now perhaps having to look into IPC rather than child AppDomains.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of [AppDomain.Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx) it is remarked that:

> If a thread does not abort, for example because it is executing
>   unmanaged code, or because it is executing a finally block, then after
>   a period of time a CannotUnloadAppDomainException is thrown in the
>   thread that originally called Unload.

This is probably your case. Look at the documentation of `PosDevice` on how to properly release the resource.

Also note that an unhandled exception thrown by a thread created in the new AppDomain will crash your whole application. In the documentation of [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) it is remarked that:

> In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, an unhandled exception
>   that occurs in a thread other than the main application thread is
>   caught by the runtime and therefore does not cause the application to
>   terminate. Thus, it is possible for the UnhandledException event to be
>   raised without the application terminating. Starting with the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0, this backstop for unhandled exceptions in child
>   threads was removed, because the cumulative effect of such silent
>   failures included performance degradation, corrupted data, and
>   lockups, all of which were difficult to debug.

Comment: I know how to properly release the POS resources (at least from what I have read), so I am still unsure as to why I cannot unload it. But yes, as you mention, in my instance using a new AppDomain does not actually solve the problem I was trying to solve. So I am struggling my way through remoting between processes at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure would this help but I founded the same error on Win 7 and XP. During app exit then the app crashed and error thrown. But the fault came from Report Viewer so when unload the form please make sure call

> reportviewer.Reset();